# onClick props in template.js not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is `onClick={this.onToggleMenuModal}` not triggering on `div id="freezer"`, whilst it is in my components by passing `onToggleMenuModal={this.handleToggleMenuModal}`?

Adding `onToggleMenuModal={this.handleToggleMenuModal}` to returned an error of `Unknown Prop Warning`

Here is the code...

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
...

class Template extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          menuModal: false,
          loading: 'is-loading'
      }
      this.handleToggleMenuModal = this.handleToggleMenuModal.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({loading: ''});
      }, 100);
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        if (this.timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
        }
    }

    handleToggleMenuModal() {
      this.setState({
        menuModal: !this.state.menuModal
      })
  }


    render() {
        const { children } = this.props

      return (
        <div id="perspective" className={`showMenu ${this.state.loading} ${this.state.menuModal ? 'animate modalview' : ''}`}>
          <Helmet>
            ...
          </Helmet>
            <div id="container">
              <Header onToggleMenuModal={this.handleToggleMenuModal} />
              <div id="wrapper">
              {children()} 
              <Footer />
              </div>
              <div id="freezer" onClick={this.onToggleMenuModal}></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  Template.propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.func,
  }

export default Template
```

Comment: your div is not a child of your Header, just pass **handleToggleMenuModal** it should work (and you can use fat arrow declaration to not have to use the bind function in the constructor

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Unfortunately, doing so returns a ` Unknown Prop Warning of <div>`

Comment: Cheers. @AndréGomes - still rather new to React but I had tried an arrow declaration as to oppose the binding. This still left the error of ` Unknown Prop Warning of <div>`

Comment: Probably an issue in your Header component because you dont a prop that has this name or you try to call **onToggleMenuModal** on your Header component but that doesnt match so it is unknow

Comment: Maybe the best solution to this is to make `<div>` Freezer a component and pass the ** handleToggleMenuModal** as with the `header`. I'll let you know.

Comment: Yes that does it - would still like to know a way to make this happen without the component but it works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put onClick inside arrow fuction like :

```
 onClick={() => {this.onToggleMenuModal}}
```

Comment: arrow function syntax is not necessary if you bind your function in the constructor. arrow function bind **this** automatically so often we use arrow function in stead of binding all function in the constructor.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution and let me know if it work for you or not.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
...

class Template extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          menuModal: false,
          loading: 'is-loading'
      }
      this.handleToggleMenuModal = this.handleToggleMenuModal.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({loading: ''});
      }, 100);
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        if (this.timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
        }
    }

    handleToggleMenuModal() {
      this.setState({
        menuModal: !this.state.menuModal
      })
  }


    render() {
        const { children } = this.props

      return (
        <div id="perspective" className={`showMenu ${this.state.loading} ${this.state.menuModal ? 'animate modalview' : ''}`}>
          <Helmet>
            ...
          </Helmet>
            <div id="container">
              <Header onToggleMenuModal={this.handleToggleMenuModal} />
              <div id="wrapper">
              {children()} 
              <Footer />
              </div>
              <div id="freezer" onClick={this.onToggleMenuModal}></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  Template.propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.func,
  }

export default Template
```

Comment: Cheers. I may be going blind but I am trying to find what the difference is here. Could you show just the suggested changes/additions. Thanks again.

Comment: You called the children as a function. You should try to call children instead of function. I'm not sure it will help you. Also you can set a default children.